# When using Sharepoint CSOM to get List of Folders/Files I get nothing, but when I log in I see files

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to use CSOM to access a Sharepoint Library to eventually upload a file. Righjt now I am having trouble jusdt being able to get to the correct Folder.

I am using the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com//sites/Industrial-IndustrialChannel/"))
        {
            ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "password")
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", securePassword);
            Web web = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            ctx.Load(list);
            ctx.Load(list.RootFolder);
            ctx.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
            ctx.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
            foreach (Folder f in fcol)
            {
                if (f.Name == "<Folder-Name>")
                {
                    ctx.Load(f.Files);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;
                    foreach (File file in fileCol)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(file.Name);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The web site title: " + web.Title);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

This is returning an empty folder collection.

However this is the collection when viewed via the UI:

[image]

Could this be a permission issue, if I only have permissions to folder, but not the site root?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to following code to get folders

```
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

FolderCollection folders = list.RootFolder.Folders;
context.Load(folders);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach(Folder folder in folders)
{
    Console.WriteLine(folder.Name);
}
```